# Domain name of a foreign brand

Tags: domains, name

I have a 20-year old domain name of a foreign brand (not currently trademarked in the US) which was used to retail imported items with that brand product in the US. This foreign brand probably does have a trademark in their own country but not a US trademark. They do export their product and there are several importers in the US and a variety of retailers. I grabbed the domain a long time ago and redirected that domain to a Vendor section of my website which sells their product. One of the importers of this brand is trying wrestle control away and claims to represent the foreign country which I highly suspect is not true. He claims he has filed an ICANN domain dispute claim. So I am wondering what are my options in this issue. I am not using the domain in "bad faith" but to retail the actual product of the foriegn brand.

Comment: Only the trademark holder or their legal representative (i.e., their lawyer) can file a [UDRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy), and all [three elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy#Process) must be demonstrated. If they don't hold a U.S. trademark and you're operating and selling in the U.S., the case would be dismissed based on that element alone. It sounds like the other distributor is trying to bluff his way into owning your domain name. Be sure to respond to the UDRP, if it ever does come.

Comment: You can search for UDRP cases by domain, complainant, or respondent [here](https://www.wipo.int/amc/en/domains/search/) by the way.

Comment: You can't do anything about nothing that has happened by a ghost.